# ajax async запрос который сразу бы выполнялся

Tags: ajax, асинхронность

У меня цикл получает name и кидает в функцию с ajax, по идеи все должно быть так:
цикл делает запись в массиве, функция с ajax дополняет ее полученными данными.
Вот как на деле:
Цикл кидает дофига запросов, и после того как он закончится выполняются одновременно все запросы ajax, который так много что получается ошибка `net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`
Вот пример кода:

```
var arr = [];
var name = 'AWP | Dragon Lore';
function handler(name, data){
    arr.push({name: name, different: data});
};
function getp(name){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://cs.money/check_skin_status?market_hash_name='+encodeURIComponent(name), 
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            handler(name, data.overstock_difference);
        }
    });
};
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    getp(name); //name будет огромный массив имен полученный с другого сайта.
};
```

Comment: можно задать async: false для ajax. При этом запросы будут выполнятся не асинхронно.

Comment: еще можно воспользоваться Promise.

Comment: И все? То есть так как я хотел никак?